# The TCP/IP connection to the host has failed. java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect Driver

Tags: java, jdbc

We deployed an application long back. It's working fine so far. 
Suddenly, we're getting the following error today when the application is trying to connect database. It's happening on and off. some times able to connect. most often getting below error.what would be the cause. Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Error:-

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed. java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
Driver name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed. java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
```

Answer (score 3):

You've run out of local ports. You have a connection leak somewhere, or you're not using a connection pool and you should be. Check `netstat -anp TCP`. You will see zillions of connections in ESTABLISHED state to the same target, the MS SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your quick response.                    Yes, There are lot of connections in TIME_WAIT state from other ports on same server. They have been killed.It's fine now.

Comment: They only last two minutes each. But you should definitely investigate the matters I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Address already in use implies that there are not enough ports on the local side available for creating a connection. You would see a lot of entries if you check the network stats. Assuming it is windows, for the exact way to get the listing, check the platform docs. For an understanding of the issue, you can also read:
http://khanna111.com/articles/TCPAAIU.html

Note that the top 2 figures on that page are jumbled. There is an explanation of the TIME_WAIT stage as well.

The cause, if you only have that one application doing jdbc running, then the probable cause could be that TCP connections to the database server are being created and either not closed or rate of creating and closing the connections is greater than a threshold that leads to this issue. You would need to investigate a connection pool in any case if you do not already have one. If there are other applications on the same host that deal with network traffic then you would need to take a look at those as well.

Comment: I did see lot of TIME_WAIT state connections from the source server with multiple port numbers. These port numbers were in incremental order (+1);                                                                                           serverip:port number from local address.  Port numbers were 49156,49157,49158...65534 . What would be the cause..?

Comment: If it is on the application side then it is that connections are closed here so it goes into time wait. Seems as if you need to check on a connection pool. Also if there are other applications running on the host then they might be the culprit as well. Check netstat -anp and confirm which application and then resolve the way I have specified earlier

Comment: a) We're not using connection pool. We do use regular JDBC connections without pool. b)There are no active applications running on this server. c) Those wait state connections didn't close even we stopped our service. It's only gone when we rebooted the server. d) We ran "netstat -anp". How can we identify which application has these TIME_WAIT connections. based on port number..? If so, It's hard to identify the application because there were TIME_WAIT connections with multiple dynamic ports (As I mentioned above). Thanks Khanna!

Comment: netstat -anp will give the process id as well on Linux. On windows I am not sure what the command is. However if you have the same process id for the connections in the TIME_WAITs then you know what process that is. You should be using a connection pool in that case.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!                                                     Here is a command for windows:  "netstat -ano"

Comment: If it helps, please help me in enhancing my reputation by ipvoting the answer and accepting it as an answer as well. Thanks.